# Normal Form and Mapping tables

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JPA application that relates two objects through a mapping table:

Wards

```
@Table(name = "wards")
    public class Ward extends AbstractBaseEntity {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -5292952700297426004L;

                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name = "facility_id")
                private Facility facility;

                @Column(name = "name", length = 20, unique = false, nullable = false)
                private String name;
            }
```

Beds

```
@Table(name = "beds")
public class Bed extends AbstractBaseEntity {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "facility_id")
                    private Facility facility;

@Column(name = "name", length = 20, unique = false, nullable = false)
 private String name;
 }
```

The mapping object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
            public class Location extends AbstractBaseEntity {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name = "facility_id")
                private Facility facility;

                @Column(name = "ward", length = 40, unique = false, nullable = true)
                private String ward;

                @Column(name = "bed", length = 40, unique = false, nullable = false)
                private String bed;
            }
```

I guess that I am being pedantic, however I am not sure that it is good to have a facility code in all three objects.  Should I just use facility in Locations or is it ok to have it referenced multiple times across the three tables?  Are there implications for managing the objects later on? I need to make sue that the records are managed as consistently as possible.

Comment: Two entities with same name?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - corrected